# runsnake fails in ubuntu with error in squaremap

Tags: python, ubuntu, cprofile

When I start runsnake with

```
$ runsnake test.profile
```

the window opens, but with no graphics and no source code (only the list of calls, etc. is present).  On the console, I see the following error message:

```
11:18:17: Debug: Adding duplicate image handler for 'PNG file'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wx/core.py", line 3282, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/runsnakerun/runsnake.py", line 701, in load
    self.SetModel(self.loader)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/runsnakerun/runsnake.py", line 738, in SetModel
    self.squareMap.SetModel(tree, self.adapter)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/squaremap/squaremap.py", line 221, in SetModel
    self.UpdateDrawing()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/squaremap/squaremap.py", line 247, in UpdateDrawing
    self.Draw(dc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/squaremap/squaremap.py", line 257, in Draw
    font = self.FontForLabels(dc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/squaremap/squaremap.py", line 267, in FontForLabels
    font.SetPointSize(scale * font.GetPointSize())
TypeError: Font.SetPointSize(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

I installed runsnake using

```
sudo apt-get install runsnake
```

The versions of the dependencies are, according to `pip list`:

```
RunSnakeRun            2.0.5
SquareMap              1.0.5
wxPython               4.0.7
```

My system is

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack is to change the code that you run by modifying the code:

```
$ sudo $EDITOR /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/squaremap/squaremap.py
```

Go to line 267

Then replace the line with:

```
font.SetPointSize(int(scale * font.GetPointSize()))
```

or hardcode someting:

```
font.SetPointSize(18)
```

Comment: Many thanks for that! It does not quite work yet: I now see a single coloured rectangle (instead of the hierarchy of rectangles) and errors such as `Traceback (most recent call last): ... File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/squaremap/squaremap.py", line 380, in DrawIconAndLabel
    dc.SetClippingRegion(x + 1, y + 1, w - 2, h - 2)  # Don't draw outside the box
TypeError: DC.SetClippingRegion(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 4 has unexpected type 'float'  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'  overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'`